# SOLR DateRange query for the current fiscal quarter

Tags: solr, typo3

I'm trying to find a way to implement a search query for a SOLR Date field that allows me to see only documents of the current quarter.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to round down by arbitrary intervals (eg. `NOW/3MONTHS`), so I'm struggling to find a way to do this regardless.

Any ideas?

Comment: Isn't it easier to send the start of the quarter directly to Solr when querying it?

Comment: @MatsLindh This is a static query set inside static configuration, so I can't send any data along with it.

Comment: Can you send any arguments at all? (since you'd be able to use NOW/3MONTHS). You can re-assign the value of NOW through the URL as well .. which parameters are adjustable by you? Do you expect it to live in `solrconfig.xml` as an invariant? Is creating a Solr extension an option? (i.e. a custom .jar file which you can add to the configuration as a static dependency)

Comment: A custom jar wouldn't be an option, and "NOW/3MONTHS" doesn't require any arguments because "NOW" is a built-in constant. It lives as a piece of TypoScript, as this will be for the back-end search field for a customer's management tool.
I could theoretically pass arguments through the TypoScript, but before having to adjust any of that, I wanted to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

there is the syntax: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_5/working-with-dates.html#date-math-syntax

```
NOW+3MONTHS
```

Or what do you mean?

Comment: That will return today + 3 months, which yes is a range of 3 months, but by "a quarter" I meant fiscal quarters, as in the time range from January to March, April to June, July to September and October to December.